# Using java scanner class failed to retrive data from txt file and set it into the targated 2d array

Tags: java, txt

the supposed output should have first 6 null repalced by 6 inner array like {1, 2, 3}, it seems the targeted array combinedArray has not get data from the file1 using scanner.

Output:[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]

'''

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner file1 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\admin\\IntellijProjects\\AlgorithmsProblemSolving2\\numbers1.txt"));
    Scanner file2 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\admin\\IntellijProjects\\AlgorithmsProblemSolving2\\numbers2.txt"));

    //loop through two files to get the total rows of the new combined 2d array
    int rowFile1 = 0;
    while (file1.hasNextLine()) {
        rowFile1++;
        file1.nextLine();
    }
    int rowFile2 = 0;
    while (file2.hasNextLine()) {
        rowFile2 ++;
        file2.nextLine();
    }
    
    int totalRow = rowFile1 + rowFile2;
    //total rows from two txt files, Initialize the 2d Array combinedArray
    int[][] combinedArray = new int[totalRow][];


    //insert files1's element into combinedArray
    while (file1.hasNextLine()) {
        for (int k = 0; k < rowFile1; k++) {
           int count = 0;
           int len = file1.nextLine().length();
           if (count < len) {
               combinedArray[k][count] = file1.nextInt();
               count ++;
           }
           file1.nextLine();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(combinedArray));
}
```

'''

Comment: "//loop through two files to get the total rows" - that is reading the whole file(s), so there is nothing left to be read and put into the array.

Comment: @user85421 you are right, i create a new scanner, but it told me that Cannot store to int array because "combinedArray[k]" is null

Comment: @ProteusYi Both of your scanners would have already reached the end when you calculate the rows. How do you expect them to again start from the start? And your "//insert file1's element into combinedArray" logic seems wrong to me

Comment: @softwareguy insert numbers of each line from files as a inner array into the array

Comment: @ProteusYi I don't get what you are saying. By the time your first two while loops are executed, the two scanners would have already reached the end in their respective files. So when you do `while(file1.hasNextLine())` in the next line, it is 
already false. So the last while loop is not executed at all.

Comment: @ProteusYi you can just add a print statement in the first line of while loop and see that it's not being executed